# Pass checkbox and text input to url for fetch for displaying data back to html

Tags: javascript, html, url, checkbox, fetch

I need to pass text values and checkbox values to a URL for a fetch request when the button is pressed and then display it on my HTML using basic Javascript.

So far I have been able to pass on text values but not the checkboxes.
They seem to always be "on"?

```
html
    <div class="form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="number" value="True">Numbers
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="character" value="ture"> Special characters
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="uppercase" value="ture">Uppercase
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="passwordbox">
      <input id="passlen" class="pass-len-box" placeholder="Enter password length">
      <button class="generatorPass" id="genratorPass">Generate</button>
      <br>
      <p id="dispPassword"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
JS
document.querySelector("#genratorPass").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const user_input_text = document.querySelector("#passlen");
  const user_input_number = (document.getElementById("number").value = "True");
  const user_input_character = (document.getElementById("character").value =
    "True");
  const user_input_uppercase = (document.getElementById("uppercase").value =
    "True");
  request(
    user_input_text,
    user_input_number,
    user_input_character,
    user_input_uppercase
  );
});
const passworldEl = document.getElementById("dispPassword");

request = (
  user_input_text,
  user_input_number,
  user_input_character,
  user_input_uppercase
) => {
  let url = `https://passwordinator.herokuapp.com?len=${user_input_text.value}&num=${user_input_number.value}&char=${user_input_character.value}&caps=${user_input_uppercase.value}`;
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data.data);
      document.querySelector("#dispPassword").innerHTML = data.data;
    });
};
```

Passing info to a password generator https://github.com/fawazsullia/password-generator

Code example
fetch('https://passwordinator.herokuapp.com') .then((res)=> res.json()) .then((data) => console.log(data))

fetch('https://passwordinator.herokuapp.com?num=true&char=true&caps=true&len=18') On resolving generates a 18 digit password with characters, alphabets, uppercase letters and numbers

Comment: What does this `document.getElementById("number").value = "True" ` Operation resolve to ?

Comment: I want it so when "number" checkbox is clicked it will pass a true value to  num=true in the URL for example 
https://passwordinator.herokuapp.com?num=true
let url = `https://passwordinator.herokuapp.com?num=${user_input_number.value}

Comment: I tried to point your attention to this Mistake. You weren't storing the Checkbox-Element into your variable `user_input_number` with this line. You were setting the checked status to true and also storing `"True"` inside your variable, which couldn't be interpreted in the `fetch()` URL, as `user_input_number.value` would be equal to `"True".value` which would fail. This issue was probably the reason for your problem.

Comment: @IISkullsII
 Wow, you got me, Yeah I can see that passing the values over now.

It seems now that the API will send data back when anything is entered as a value for example https://passwordinator.herokuapp.com/?num=r&len=4
will return dka6.

I'm not sure if that's my code or the API.

If its the API I think I would have to have the checkbox add the "num=true" when clicked 
passwordinator.herokuapp.com?num=true 
and when unclicked don't add the "num=ture"
passwordinator.herokuapp.com?

Or Have I gone mad?

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code, see.

```js
document.querySelector("#genratorPass").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const user_input_text = document.querySelector("#passlen");
  const user_input_number = document.getElementById("number").checked
  const user_input_character = document.getElementById("character").checked
  const user_input_uppercase = document.getElementById("uppercase").checked
  request(
    user_input_text,
    user_input_number,
    user_input_character,
    user_input_uppercase
  );
});
const passworldEl = document.getElementById("dispPassword");

request = (
  user_input_text,
  user_input_number,
  user_input_character,
  user_input_uppercase
) => {
  let url = `https://passwordinator.herokuapp.com?len=${user_input_text.value}&num=${user_input_number}&char=${user_input_character}&caps=${user_input_uppercase}`;
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data.data);
      document.querySelector("#dispPassword").innerHTML = data.data;
    });
};
```

```html
    <div class="form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="number" value="True">Numbers
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="character" value="ture"> Special characters
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="uppercase" value="ture">Uppercase
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="passwordbox">
      <input id="passlen" class="pass-len-box" placeholder="Enter password length">
      <button class="generatorPass" id="genratorPass">Generate</button>
      <br>
      <p id="dispPassword"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what modifications you made? What did you do that fixed the problem?